# i cant do npm run dev

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, npm-install

i tried to clone my friends project from git, and it says

```
Vite manifest not found at: D:\laravel\PBL-Kelompok-5-2\public\build/manifest.json

Start the development server
Run npm run dev in your terminal and refresh the page.
```

so i tried to type npm run dev on my terminal and cmd, but still cant work. i tried type npm install, npm -g install, etc, and the tried to type npm run dev, it still cant work. the error says

```
D:\laravel\PBL-Kelompok-5-2>npm install

added 138 packages, removed 238 packages, and audited 139 packages in 2s

35 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

D:\laravel\PBL-Kelompok-5-2>npm run dev
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\laravel\PBL-Kelompok-5-2\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.11.1
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\laravel\PBL-Kelompok-5-2\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.11.1
```

idk what happened, i already tried turend off my windows firewall, it still cant work too

please help me, this is for my school project. sorry in advance about any grammar mistakes

Comment: backup everything, then delete the node_modules, npm install and finally run npm run dev

Comment: @nickfreeman This version mismatch problem, probably your nodejs/npm version doesn't match one of the libraries in package.json, please ask the proper node version from your friend which they used for this project (in case it's not already in package.json). then install that version and then try `npm install` again . Check [nvm](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/) for nodej version management

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

A module not found error basically says that that a modules doesn't exists (or the entrypoint file), so check if this directory exists:

```
'D:\laravel\PBL-Kelompok-5-2\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
```

If it doesn't, this might be a cache or broken module issue.
Your package.json is stating that you need a module and this module for some reason is not available in the build.

I suggest you do the following:

```
  $ rm -rf node_modules
  $ npm cache clean --force
  $ npm install
```

These commands will respectively: remove your node_modules folder, clean npm cache and reinstall all modules again.

The last option: you can reinstall nodeJs as it can be a root problem (a problem that not lies in your project).

Answer (score -1):

It is 100% due to node or npm versions. Verify firstly that you have the required versions installed by running

```
node -v
npm -v
```

If you do and it still gives errors then I recommend reinstalling npm like

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

But make sure to verify the dependencies in package.json before you do this. It will be under `dependencies:npm` most likely

If that doesn't work, manully delete the node_modules and run `npm i` again

Comment: i already manually deleted the node modules, and run npm i. but it still gives me the same error. it says it cannot find module